# how to mimic html button in c#

Tags: c#, html, button

I have this button in my html

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/mep/dashboard" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="elkpaypal1@gmail.com" />

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My painting" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00"/> 
<input type="submit" value="Buy!" />

</asp:Content>
```

I need to dynamically assign a value to where the 10.00 is. If there anyone way to do this? I am more familiar with c# than I am html. Is there a way to mimic this button is c# so that I could assign that value by pulling it from a label?

Comment: I suppose that by dinamically you mean read from database and set this corresponding value into a button value, am I right? If that's it, you need to iterate through ddbb query response (usually called rows) and print your tagged html from inside this iteration (loop)

Comment: It doesn't need to be from a database.There is a label in the application that contains the correct value. The issue is that the label is a sum of certain values and will seldom be the same.

Comment: You'll need to read those sepparate values, and set it into the value after the sum, and before printing the view. I can't provide code i didn't used c# for a long time (and i hate it a little bit)  i tell you the logic, maybe other can bring light over your logic behaviour a way more explicit

Comment: Looks like asp webforms? Use asp hidden control or put `runat="server"` with ID on the element. Then you should be able to access the control via on C#. Then you can set the label value from aspx code behind